# Schedule an event for a certain unix timestamp in Python

Tags: python, scheduler

How to implement the following?

```
def thirty_seconds_in():
    print('meow')

at_time( time() + 30, thirty_seconds_in )
```

Do I need my own thread/runloop with a `sleep(.01)` in it?

Comment: Check the python `sched` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Comment: Did you try simple_scheduler...? You don't need any for loop. The library does all the work for you. https://pypi.org/project/simple-scheduler/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is, like you said, to implement your own loop.

The second solution is to use some given library functions like [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html).

But in fact you need a runtime loop that will perform a check.